# An item in IEnumerable does not equal an item in List

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda, ienumerable

I just can't figure out why the item in my filtered list is not found. I have simplified the example to show it. I have a class Item...

```
public class Item
{
    public Item(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

... and a class 'Items' which should filter the items and check if the first item is still in the list...

```
public class Items
{
    private IEnumerable<Item> _items;

    public Items(IEnumerable<Item> items)
    {
        _items = items;
    }

    public List<Item> Filter(string word)
    {
        var ret = new List<Item>(_items.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(word)));

        Console.WriteLine("found: " + ret.Contains(_items.First()));
        // found: false

        return ret;
    }
}
```

The executing code looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] itemNames = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };

    Items list = new Items(itemNames.Select(x => new Item(x)));
    list.Filter("a");

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Now, if I execute the program, the Console.WriteLine outputs that the item is not found. But why?

If I change the first line in the constructor to

```
 _items = items.ToList()
```

then, it can find it. If I undo that line and call ToList() later in the Filter-method, it also cannot find the item?!

```
public class Items
{
    private IEnumerable<Item> _items;

    public Items(IEnumerable<Item> items)
    {
        _items = items;
    }

    public List<Item> FilteredItems
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public List<Item> Filter(string word)
    {
        var ret = new List<Item>(_items.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(word)));

        _items = _items.ToList();
        Console.WriteLine("found: " + ret.Contains(_items.First()));
        // found: false

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Why is there a difference where and when the lambda expression is executed and why isn't the item found any more? I don't get it!

Comment: you are initializing a new item every time when you call`x => new Item(x)));`. using `Select`

Comment: Thanks guys. It is so obvious, but I didnt see it. I should quit working for today :D

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The reason is **deferred execution**.

You intialize the `_items` field to

```
itemNames.Select(x => new Item(x));
```

This is a *query*, not the *answer* to that query. This query is *executed* every time you iterate over `_items`.

So in this line of your `Filter` method:

```
var ret = new List<Item>(_items.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(word)));
```

the source array is enumerated and a `new Item(x)` created for each string. These items are stored in your list `ret`.

When you call `Contains(_items.First())` after that, `First()` **again** executes the *query* in `_items`, creating **new** `Item` instances for each source string.

Since `Item`'s `Equals` method is probably not overridden and performs a simple reference equality check, the first `Item` returned from the second iteration is a different instance of `Item` than the one in your list.

Answer (score 10):

Let's remove extra code to see the problem:

```
var itemNames = new [] { "a", "b", "c" };
var items1 = itemNames.Select(x => new Item(x));
var surprise = items1.Contains(items1.First());   // False
```

The collection `items1` appears not to contain its initial element! ([demo](http://ideone.com/VVSu2D))

Adding `ToList()` fixes the problem:

```
var items2 = itemNames.Select(x => new Item(x)).ToList();
var noSurprise = items2.Contains(items2.First()); // True
```

The reason why you see different results with and without `ToList()` is that (1) `items1` is evaluated lazily, and (2) your `Item` class does not implement `Equals`/`GetHashCode`. Using `ToList()` makes default equality work; implementing custom equality check would fix the problem for multiple enumeration.

The main lesson from this exercise is that storing `IEnumerable<T>` that is passed to your constructor is dangerous. This is only one of the reasons; other reasons include multiple enumeration and possible modification of the sequence *after* your code has validated its input. You should call `ToList` or `ToArray` on sequences passed into constructors to avoid these problems:

```
public Items(IEnumerable<Item> items) {
    _items = items.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems in your code.

**First problem** is that you are initializing a new item every time. That is you don't store the actual items here when you write.

```
IEnumerable<Item> items = itemNames.Select(x => new Item(x));
```

The execution of `Select` is deferred. i.e every time you call `.ToList()` a new set of Items is created using `itemNames` as source.

**Second problem** is that you are comparing items by reference here.

```
Console.WriteLine("found: " + ret.Contains(_items.First()));
```

When you use `ToList` you store items in list and the references remains same so you will find item with reference.

When you don't use `ToList` the references are not same any more. because everytime a new Item is created. you cant find your item with different reference.